# How to navigate at the end of a Redux action?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I want to use only `React`, `React Redux`, `React Router` and `Redux Thunk`.

I want to navigate to a dashboard page when a successful user creation action is dispatched. Here is my async action creator,

```
export function createUser() {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(creatingUser());
    return axios.post('/api/users').then(() => {
      // how to navigate to dashboard after this action is dispatched?
      dispatch(createdUser());
    });
  };
}
```

Can you show me exactly where is the place I should [naviage programmatically](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md)?

Comment: Does `createdUser()` return a promise?

Comment: `createUser()` returns a function to perform asynchronous dispatch like `creatingUser()` and `createdUser`.

Comment: Well, it couldn't hurt to try doing `dispatch(createdUser()).then(navigateToAnotherPage)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initially looking, I would hope that "createdUser" returns a promise (like @idbehold asked previously)

in a nutshell, something like this.

```
// make sure your function createdUser returns a promise
function createdUser() {
 return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   //simulate some api request
   setTimeout( () =>{
     // api resolves. in the .then() do:
     resolve()
   }, 4000)
 })
}

// the dispatch will forward resolution of the promise ahead into the 
// .then.. then you can redirect.
dispatch(createdUser()).then( ()=> {
  console.log("NAVIGATING AWAY")
  //browserHistory.push('/some/path')
  //assuming you are importing browserHistory
})
```

I hope I was helpful, if not :-( , perhaps I didn't fully understand what your need is/was. Let me know, and I'll try to help further.

Comment: `createdUser()` is just a plain action creator without returning a promise, but following the same idea I can just navigate right after the action is dispatched like this,
<pre>
    export function createUser() {
      return dispatch => {
        dispatch(creatingUser());
        return axios.post('/api/users').then(() => {
          dispatch(createdUser());
          browserHistory.push('/dashboard');
        });
      };
    }

I was thinking it wasn't a good place to have navigation logic in the Redux action creator.